# can I run an sql query inside a while statement that refers to another sql query in its condition area?

Tags: php, sql, while-loop

My code is as follows

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $active_bid_ids = array_unique($row);
    $item_id = $active_bid_ids['item_id'];
    echo $item_id;
    echo '<br />';
    $sql = "SELECT item_name FROM items_list WHERE id='$item_id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $cn) or
        die(mysql_error($cn));
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $item_name = $row['item_name'];
    echo $item_name;
}
```

and it seems like the query gets run only one time if I have the additional sql query in the middle whereas is I remove the line

```
$sql = "SELECT item_name FROM items_list WHERE id='$item_id'";
```

the while function runs as normal and returns many results.

Comment: You made mistake somewhere. But it still is not a good idea to perform query in a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reusing your $result variable and $row variable which is throwing off your loop.

try:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $active_bid_ids = array_unique($row);
   $item_id = $active_bid_ids['item_id'];
   echo $item_id;
   echo '<br />';
   $sql = "SELECT item_name FROM items_list WHERE id='$item_id'";
   $innerresult = mysql_query($sql, $cn) or
      die(mysql_error($cn));
   $innerrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($innerresult);
   $item_name = $innerrow['item_name'];
   echo $item_name;
}
```

Comment: Best practice tips: parameterize your queries to avoid potential security vulnerabilities, and accomplish what you want in this case with a JOIN like this: `SELECT I.item_name, A.active_bids_ids FROM active_bids A INNER JOIN items_list I on A.item_id = I.id`

Comment: thank you for pointing out best practices. I will definitely be checking that out and studying a bit more before I finalize my code.